# Static method getting called using a null reference

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = null;
    test.func();
  }

  static void func(){
    System.out.println("Hello!!");
  }      
}
```

Why this program is getting executed successfully?

Answer (score 3):

This is because static methods are not related to instances. Compiler internally convert this and call Test.func()

Answer (score 0):

You call a static method. Static methods are invoked on Classes.

The call is like this `Test.func()`.

**Tip**: In your code when you call static methods. Call them `Class.method()` not on object.